# subtracting 2 seismic unix files

Tags: subtraction

I hope that you are familiar with Seismic Unix (su) for displaying wiggle. I've tried but can't find a way of subtracting the values in these two files.

If you have been working with Seismic Unix and have any ideas, would you please give a recommendation ?

Comment: I don't know enough wiggle to decide if this is a programming question ;-)

Comment: But perhaps superuser or http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for this topic

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion @Marged. I would try to ask there !! Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked for a cross-post on the Earthscience stackexchange but didn't see it.

Anyway, you have two ways to subtract two files, assuming they are identical with respect to number of traces, samples per trace and sampling rate:

```
sudiff file1.su file2.su > diff.su
```

or:

```
suop2 file1.su file2.su op=diff > diff.su
```

They are equivalent.

Comment: Wow...great !! Thank you very much !! It really works !! I couldn't believe it's that simple. I've gone around around, keep googleing but there was no such a name of sudiff !! 

Very grateful about that !!

Comment: If you haven't checked the manual for SU, you can find one here:  http://www.cwp.mines.edu/cwpcodes/documentation/

also, if you look through your $CWPROOT/bin directory, you can see all the programs. If you run one with no arguments, it should pull up the self-doc file that explains what each program does.

Comment: Many thanks !! Many thanks !! I've always had them with me but somehow I've missed that important command for my stuff !! 

Very useful for me. I am appreciate your help !!